# Administrate Field::Select custom display value with symbols

Tags: ruby-on-rails, administrate

I'm pretty new to both Ruby and Administrate. I have a type where I want users to choose from a dropdown of operators *and* display those operators as their symbols.

I was able to achieve operator symbols in the database and dropdown with this code (edited for brevity)

```rb
class CompatibilityRule < ApplicationRecord
    #...
    enum comparison: { eq: "==", ne: "!=", gt: ">", lt: "<", ge: ">=", le: "<="}
end

class CompatibilityRuleDashboard < Administrate::BaseDashboard
  ATTRIBUTE_TYPES = {
    #...
    comparison: Field::Select.with_options(searchable: false, 
      collection: CompatibilityRule.comparisons.values,
      ),
    # ...
  }.freeze
```

[image: Dropdown shows operator symbols]

But the operator still shows up as the key value in list views and detail pages

[image]

I've tried using symbols in the enum keys, but it throws the error

> You tried to define an enum named "comparison" on the model "CompatibilityRule", but this will generate a class method "==", which is already defined by ActiveRecord::Relation

I've also tried looking through Administrate's issues and guides, but `Field:Select` [doesn't appear to any other configuration for display](http://administrate-demo.herokuapp.com/customizing_dashboards).

Is there any way I can display the symbols everywhere the enum displayed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out a solution. A bit awkward, but you can add spaces to the keys. It solves the conflict with existing operators and looks correct in the UI.

```rb
enum comparison: { " == ": "==", " != ": "!=", " > ": ">", " < ": "<", " >= ": ">=", " <= ": "<="}
```